# Lock screen not working

Tags: wingpanel, greeter, keyboard-shortcuts, suspend

When i use the shortcut keys Win+L, click the Lock option in wingpanel-session menu, or when i suspend, lock doesn't work.

`dm-tool lock` works.
`light-locker-command --lock` shows:

```
Received error message from the locker: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files
```

If i install gnome-screensaver lock screen works for sleep and shortcut keys, but not from the wingpanel-session menu. It also displays differently.

Any idea how to get this working? I just fresh-installed Elementary (Juno).

Comment: I couldn't solve the problem, so i just installed Elementary again and it has been working so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove disable-light-locker package from the system.